# Azure subscription has ended. How do I export the database now?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I had a $100 student subscription. Now it has expired and I lost access. How can I export data from my database?

Comment: try contact their support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the subscription is expired, you cannot access the data or resources in your subscription.

Either upgrade to Pay-as-you-go subscription or contact Microsoft support team via New Support Request.

Comment: Note that obvious typo-based questions are off-topic since it won't help anyone else in the future -> [Should I answer off-topic questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/133552/should-i-answer-off-topic-questions)